# Google Cloud Endpoints: How to parse array-style GET query string?

Tags: api, google-app-engine, query-string, google-cloud-endpoints, request.querystring

I am building a Google Cloud Endpoints API which receives the following query string via GET:

`?count=10&page=1&sorting[title_column]=desc`

Unfortunately when creating a resource container there is no dictionary data type in the Message.messages class.  I cannot access either the key or value of the 'sorting' dictionary in the GET query string.  This resource container does not work:

> ```
> REQUEST_RESOURCE_CONTAINER = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
>     message_types.VoidMessage,
>     count=messages.IntegerField(2),
>     page=messages.IntegerField(3),
>     sorting=messages.StringField(4)
> )
> ```

Are there any suggestions?  I can't change the way the client program accesses this API and I really wanted to implement this using Google Cloud Endpoints.